# Stubbing of "watchPosition" in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I try to inject position changes to an JS/REACT-Application. The Application registering at `window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`. My idea is to stub the "watchPosition" method to get a handle on the callback function. Then calling the callback function from the application directly.

Like:

```
    const watchPositionFake = (successCallback, errorCallback, options) => {
        console.debug("PROXY set callback watchPosition");
        originalWatchPositionSuccessCallback = successCallback;
    };

    cy.visit("/", {
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
            cy.stub(win.navigator.geolocation, "watchPosition").callsFake(watchPositionFake);
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work with function registering in the Application on the `watchPosition`. But this does work with function in the cypress-step file. (Working as in in the console.log I see changes in position according to the values I send in via `originalWatchPositionSuccessCallback` ).

Any idea who to fake a position change?

Comment: I have feeling that `onBeforeLoad(win)` is too soon, if React is adding it's watcher in javascript after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different way to solve the issue of getting the callbacks of the registered function to `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` triggered. The code in the question tried to solve this by `cy.stub(win.navigator.geolocation, "watchPosition")`, but this turned to be not working reliably (too soon, too late, different browser/window context, another iframe, ...), the precise reason varied.

An alternative solution to trigger the registered watchPosition callbacks without modifying the production code is the undocumented cypress (v6.2) automation interface in cypress to CDP.

```
export const setFakePosition = position => {
    // https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setGeolocationOverride
    console.debug(`cypress::setGeolocationOverride with position ${JSON.stringify(position)}`);
    cy.log("**setGeolocationOverride**").then(() =>
        Cypress.automation("remote:debugger:protocol", {
            command: "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
            params: {
                latitude: position.latitude,
                longitude: position.longitude,
                accuracy: 50
            }
        })
    );
};
```

And verifying with:

```
let positionLogSpy;
When("vehicle is located in {string}", city => {
    const position = cityLocationMap[city];
    cy.window()
        .then(win => {
            const expectedLogMessage = `new position lat: ${position.latitude}, lng: ${position.longitude}`;
            positionLogSpy = cy.spy(win.console, "log").withArgs(expectedLogMessage);
        })
        .then(() => {
            setFakePosition(position);
        });
});

Then("vehicle has moved to {string}", () => {
    expect(positionLogSpy).to.be.called;
});
```